# Read php var from Python

Tags: php, python

Here is my code, that is supposed to work according to answers to other similar questions, but it does not.

PHP:

```
    <?PHP

$par = $_POST["parameter"];
$importPar=exec("py pyData.py . $par"); //also tried shell_exec()
print ($par);
print($importPar);
?>
```

Python:

```
import sys
who = sys.argv[1]
print("This is php var: ",who)
```

It might have to do something with my cmd because nothing is returned even when I try:

```
$test=shell_exec('ipconfig');
echo $test;
```

Comment: Side note: Python can be called directly from a web request by using CGI/WSGI.  There's probably no need here to use PHP to call a python script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With minor modifications, your code works just fine on my PHP 5.6.3 setup.  The only substantive difference in my example below is that `$par` gets set locally, and not from a `$POST` input.

Minor corrections:
1. The `.` isn't necessary when you're including a `$variable` inside double quotes.  This will actually make python think you want to print `.` instead of `$par`, as `.` is read as `sys.argv[1]`.
2. I'm assuming `py` is an alias, but I needed to use `python` in `exec()` to run properly.
3. You'll get a tuple as print output with your python statement as-is: `('This is php var: ', 'foo')`
.  Consider using `.format()` instead, see below.

```
""" test.py
import sys
who = sys.argv[1]
print('This is php var: {}'.format(who))
"""

<?PHP
$par = "foo";
$importPar=exec("python test.py $par"); 
print ("$par\n");
print($importPar);
?>
```

Output:

```
foo
This is php var: test.py
Process finished with exit code 0
```